# Why Firebase messaging shows 0 messages sent

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, sendmessage

Notifications are received successfully. When I look in to Firebase cloud messaging graph the open count was 0 for all notification, whereas the sends count was 14,568. And personally know some users have clicked the notification. But still the count remains 0.

Do let me know how to fix it. Thanks in advance.
[sample notification message graph attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgG8B.png)

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? We are seeing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install Firebase Analytics in order to see those counts updated.